# How to reduce the size of the chapter numbers?

Tags: classicthesis

I would like to reduce a little bit the size of the chapter number in `classic thesis`. How could I do that?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,twoside=semi,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\begin{document}

\chapter{A title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, I would never have guessed that additional spaces in package names work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good occasion for avoiding to perpetuate the wrong usage of `\newfont` in `classicthesis`.

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  openany,
  twoside=semi,
  footinclude=true,
  headinclude=true
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
  %eulerchapternumbers,
  parts,
  pdfspacing,
  dottedtoc
]{classicthesis}

\makeatletter
\if@eulerchapternumbers
  \DeclareFixedFont{\chapterNumber}{U}{eur}{b}{n}{60}
\else
  \DeclareFixedFont{\chapterNumber}{T1}{pplj}{m}{n}{60}
\fi
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{A title}
\end{document}
```

Set the size you prefer, in this example it is 60pt instead of the default 70pt.

Comment: If `\font` is so bad, then someone should fix `classicthesis.cls`. Otherwise one stays on the safe side by keeping to the original as closely as possible, avoiding any unintended side effects (keeping even the problems the original may have). And `classicthesis` uses `\font`.  Imho the wrong place to start preaching. But, no doubt, yours is the solution in line with modern LaTeX.

Comment: I think to have said it to André Miede several years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Redefine the font command `\chapterNumber` to the font (and scaling factor) you prefer.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,twoside=semi,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classic thesis}
\font\chapterNumber=pplr9d scaled 6000\relax % Original value: 7000
\begin{document}
\chapter{A title}
\end{document}
```

Original scaling factor 7000:

> [image]

Modified scaling factor 6000:

> [image]

Note that this redefinition will render the package option `eulerchapternumbers` void. Instead, if you want to use rescaled Euler fonts for the chapter numbers, change the command to

```
\font\chapterNumber=eurb10 scaled 6000\relax
```

Comment: `\font` should never be used in a LaTeX document.